# Почему после адаптации под мобильное устройство, блок с классом .brand в инструментах браузера становится пустым

Tags: html, css

```css
.brand {
  width: 980px;
  height: 175px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: block;
}

.brand-item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 175px;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .brand {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .brand-item {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="brand">
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы задаете ему `height: auto` для разрешения 480 пикселей и меньше, а внутри него элементы с `float: left`, после которых блок не расчищается. Рекомендую почитать о [clearfix](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Прислушайтесь к Sasha Omelchenko.
Если у Вас только один блок с элементами `float: left`, тогда просто к родителю `.brand-item`, то есть **`.brand`** прописать **`::after`**

```css
.brand {
  width: 980px;
  height: 175px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  display: block;
}
.brand::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.brand-item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 175px;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .brand {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .brand-item {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 120px;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="brand">
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
  <div class="brand-item"></div>
</section>
```